# Binding values to user control but it returns me null

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my webfrom, I have a repeater which is getting some item information from a webservice, and the output is list.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
          <uc1:ItemDetailsUserControl runat="server" ID="ItemDetailsUserControl1"  HotelCode='Eval("Item.Code")' CityCode='<%#Eval("City.Code")%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

To get the details for each item, I am having this definition in my usercontrol - ItemDetailsUserControl,

```
    public string ItemCode { set; get; }
    public string CityCode { set; get; }
```

and this is user control code behind,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //do some stuff 
       response.write(ItemCode); //null
       response.write(CityCode); //null
    }
```

the problem is in binding in repeater. when i get the eval it simply returns me the value but when i pass it as a attribute it returns null value.

Comment: In the `Page_Load` event the repeater is not yet filled - the properties are empty at this moment.

Comment: so stupid, im stuck for a day for this stupid issue, i have no idea why i didnt check that :D anyway tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the values of the properties too yearly - in the `Page_Load` event the repeater control is not yet filled with the data. One possible solution would be to move your code to the [`Page_PreRender` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

An example of retrieveing and using resp. changing the data bound to the repeater can be found here: http://runnable.com/UjMj269qAWwQAAB3/asp-net-how-to-use-repeater.

To match your case in the given example, add this code to the existing one:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstEmployees.Count > 0)
    {
      lstEmployees.First().FirstName = "Test";
      rptEmployees.DataSource = lstEmployees;
     //You need to rebind the repeater
      rptEmployees.DataBind();
    }
}

private List<Employee> lstEmployees = new List<Employee>();
```

The output: http://runnable.com/VBQHUzNw-OxoDUWX/output.